# Jackson error in ElasticSearch Hadoop while loading data to ElasticSearch

Tags: jackson, hive, apache-pig, elasticsearch-hadoop

I am trying to load data from `HDFS` to `ElasticSearch` using `elasticsearch-hadoop` version `elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.Beta3.jar`.

There was a bug on Mapr: 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/215
which was supposed to fix the `jackson` issue. But it is still taking the `jackson` jars from the Hadoop directory which has `jackson` version 1.5.

I have added `REGISTER` commands to register 1.8 jars:

```
REGISTER /opt/mapr/hive/hive/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar;
REGISTER /opt/mapr/hive/hive/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar;
REGISTER /opt/mapr/hive/hive/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar;
REGISTER /opt/mapr/hive/hive/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar;
```

But I am still getting the following error:

```
2015-04-17 05:49:03,760 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: 
Error: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.reader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectReader;
```

I tried the same with Hive and getting the same error as well.

Comment: I think that you should report this issue for on the elasticsearch-hadoop repo

Comment: thanks, raised the issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/425